Filling DataFrame columns by index range
Suppose to have two lists, namely indexes and values of the same lenght.
I want to add a column to an existing DataFrame, e.g. df["Values"] using these lists, in particular by assigning values[0] to all rows with index bewteen 0 and indexes[0], then values[1] to all rows with index bewteen indexes[0] and indexes[1] and so on...
At this point I was only able to get this result by iterating over all the dataframes with the df.iterrows() method, but this is rather slow when the size of the dataframe (csv) is about 20 MB.
Is there an elegant way to get the same result without using a for loop but a pandas method or similar?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You should provide a small mre. Look into merge_asof. Eg. you could try something like (df your dataframe): pd.merge_asof(df.reset_index(), pd.DataFrame({"index": indexes, "Values": values}), direction="forward").assign(Values=lambda df: df["Values"].ffill()).drop(columns="index").

IIUC, you can use pandas.cut.
Inclusive of the right index:
df = pd.DataFrame({"Data": range(10)})

indexes = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

df["Values"] = pd.cut(df.index, bins=[-1] + indexes, labels=values)

   Data Values
0     0      1
1     1      1
2     2      1
3     3      2
4     4      2
5     5      3
6     6      3
7     7      4
8     8      4
9     9      5

Exclusive of the right index:
df["Values"] = pd.cut(df.index, bins=[-1] + indexes, labels=values, right=False)

   Data Values
0     0      1
1     1      1
2     2      2
3     3      2
4     4      3
5     5      3
6     6      4
7     7      4
8     8      5
9     9      5


You could do something like:
df = pd.DataFrame({'Values': []})
partition1 = pd.Series([values[0] for _ in range(indexes[0])])
partition2 = pd.Series([values[1] for _ in range(indexes[0], indexes[1])])
df['Values'] = pd.concat([partition1, partition2], ignore_index=True)

and if you have more partitions you automate it with a for loop on the number of partitions.

Expanding on the answer from Simone:
def repeat(values, indexes):
    """
    Create a new list filled with values from list "values" with the corresponding index from "indexes"
    as the maximum index to fill up to.
    Example:
    Given values=[7,4,8] and indexes=[3,5,7] the value values[0]=7 should be repeated from index 0 to indexes[0]
    in the new list, the value values[1]=4 should be repeated from indexes[0]+1 to indexes[1] and so on.    
    """
    if len(values) != len(indexes):
        raise ValueError(f'Length of values and indexes has to be the same, got len(values) = {len(values)} and len(indexes) = {len(indexes)}')
    
    expanded_indexes = indexes.copy()
    expanded_indexes.insert(0, -1)

    repetition = [values[j-1] for j in range(1, len(expanded_indexes)) for _ in range(expanded_indexes[j-1], expanded_indexes[j])]
    
    return repetition

df = pd.DataFrame()
# insert other data in df
values = [7,4,8]
indexes = [3,5,7]
repeating_list = repeat(values, indexes)
df['Values'] = repeating_list

